# Why in order to compare hijri with iso dates you need to wrap a DateTime in LocalDateTime? (Joda)

Tags: java, datetime, calendar, jodatime, gregorian-calendar

I am trying to convert an ISO (Gregorian) date into a hijri (Islamic) date and the compare the first to a hijri date.

What I do and it does not work is:

```
    Chronology iso = ISOChronology.getInstanceUTC();
    Chronology hijri = IslamicChronology.getInstanceUTC();

    DateTime dtISO = new DateTime("2015-03-12T10:04:43", iso);

    System.out.println("dtISO: " + dtISO);
    DateTime toHijri = new DateTime(dtISO, hijri);
    System.out.println("toHijri: " + toHijri); // 1436-05-21T10:04:43.000Z
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY-MM-dd HH-mm");

    DateTime hijriDt = new DateTime(formatter.parseDateTime("1442-05-21 10-10"), iso);

    if (hijriDt.isAfter(toHijri)) {
        System.out.println("hijriDt date is after toHijri date");
    }
    if (hijriDt.isBefore(toHijri)) {
        System.out.println("hijriDt date is before toHijri date");
    }
    if (hijriDt.isEqual(toHijri)) {
        System.out.println("hijriDt date is equal toHijri date");
    }
```

No matter what the hijri date is it always returns "hijriDt date is before toHijri date".

Now as I was experimenting I tried this:

```
    Chronology iso = ISOChronology.getInstanceUTC();
    Chronology hijri = IslamicChronology.getInstanceUTC();

    LocalDateTime toHijri = new LocalDateTime(new DateTime("2015-03-12T10:04:43", iso), hijri);
    System.out.println("toHijri: " + toHijri); // 1436-05-21T10:04:43.000Z
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY-MM-dd HH-mm");

    LocalDateTime hijriDt = new LocalDateTime(formatter.parseDateTime("1442-05-21 10-10"), iso);

    if (hijriDt.isAfter(toHijri)) {
        System.out.println("hijriDt date is after toHijri date");
    }
    if (hijriDt.isBefore(toHijri)) {
        System.out.println("hijriDt date is before toHijri date");
    }
    if (hijriDt.isEqual(toHijri)) {
        System.out.println("hijriDt date is equal toHijri date");
    }
```

which works like a charm. Notice how the toHijri date is constructed:
    LocalDateTime toHijri = new LocalDateTime(new DateTime("2015-03-12T10:04:43", iso), hijri);

A DateTime instance is wrapped inside a LocalDateTime.

Why is this happening? Why the first block does not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not what you want:

```
DateTime hijriDt = new DateTime(formatter.parseDateTime("1442-05-21 10-10"), iso);
```

That's not using the Hijri calendar *anywhere*:

- Your formatter is using ISO (by default)
- You're parsing a date in year 1442 ISO, which isn't what you want
- You're then "converting" that into the ISO calendar (which it already is)
- Your variable name suggests that you're expecting it to be in the Hijri calendar, but it's not

I suspect you want:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm")
    .withChronology(hijri);
DateTime hijriDt = formatter.parseDateTime("1442-05-21 10-10");
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. Do you know why the second block works? Is "LocalDateTime toHijri" treated as iso although it has been converted to hijri?

Comment: @ampofila: I suspect it's not *really* working - it's just giving you the comparison answer you expected. I don't have the time to check why at the moment, but it's definitely not a Hijri date...

Comment: Found it. The way LocalDateTime instances are compared is different than DateTime instances. The first simply compares each field in order, from largest to smallest (from the docs) while the second compares milliseconds.

Comment: @ampofila: Eek, without checking chronologies? That's horrible, and surprises me.

Comment: Check compareTo method in https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/blob/master/src/main/java/org/joda/time/base/AbstractPartial.java. It seems to me that it only checks integers. As far as DateTime is concerned (https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/blob/master/src/main/java/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.java) I do not see the chronology getting involved in the comparison, but I suppose they use chronology to create the instants.

Comment: @ampofila: Indeed. That feels like a pretty nasty bug to me :(